# Enveloping data in Maps in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am getting image counts using this method in my Elixir app:

```
Enum.each(0..23, fn(per_hour) ->
  count = hour(camera_exid, date_unix, per_hour)
end)
```

I want to map `per_hour` and `count` into a `Map`, which I can later pass that to a view. Something in the format of:

```
[%{hour: per_hour, count: count}, %{hour: per_hour, count: count}, ...]
```

Comment: Please provide the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Now there are many glitches with your code: you are spawning 24 agents for no reason, your code treats `hour` as both function and number, `Enum.filter(fn(item) -> item end)` is redundant, in `render` you might simply do: `def render("yesterday.json", %{camera: _, details: _} = data), do: data` by tuning the map keys etc. Please show us the data you have and the data you want to transform them into.

Comment: Sir am using agent to count the image counts. I have update the code please check now

Comment: @mudasobwa You can see now sir.. What I am trying to do here.. also am counting the loop with agent

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do. Like @mudasobwa said, please re-write your question to explain your exact issue.

Comment: @Sheharyar updated

Comment: As a side note, `%{}` is a Map, not a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enum.each` simply applies a function over each item in a list, it doesn't return anything. You should use [**`Enum.map/2`**](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#map/2):

```
list = Enum.map 0..23, fn per_hour ->
  %{
      hour:  per_hour,
      count: hour(camera_exid, date_unix, per_hour)
   }
end
```

Assuming your methods/variables `camera_exid` and `date_unix` are available to you in the scope, your final output would be of the format:

```
[%{hour: per_hour, count: count}, %{hour: per_hour, count: count}, ...]
```

Comment: can we save that into a variable as well? like list? [] ?

Comment: I meant like wrapped in [%{}, %{}]

Comment: Coudnt stop myself to just accept the answer you are great! thanks

Comment: Yes the final output will be of that format. Please read the docs on [`Enum.map`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#map/2)